# My htaccess rule not wroking for a project on live server (htaccess is inside the folder)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

What i am trying to do:

On my server, for a particular project, I want to write URL-Rriting rules through htaccess (remove .php or .html extension from URL).

My Site Url:

http://enacteservices.com/EpcGroup/

And:

http://www.enacteservices.com/EpcGroup/contact

Now if you look second URL .php extension is removed perfectly but it shows `Page Not Found` while the page is there.

If I wrote there: http://www.enacteservices.com/EpcGroup/contact.php

It starts working.

What I have tried to write in .htaccess (this file is inside my folder):

### First

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /EpcGroup/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
    
    #Removes access to the system folder by users.

    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

    #previously this would not have been possible.

    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder

    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder

    #Submitted by: Fabdrol

    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]



    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,

    #such as an image or CSS document, if this isn't true it sends the

    #request to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's

    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin



    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

### Second: Added (EpcGroup/):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /EpcGroup/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
    
    #Removes access to the system folder by users.

    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

    #previously this would not have been possible.

    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ EpcGroup/admin/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder

    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder

    #Submitted by: Fabdrol

    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ EpcGroup/index.php?/$1 [L]



    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,

    #such as an image or CSS document, if this isn't true it sends the

    #request to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ EpcGroup/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's

    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
    ErrorDocument 404 EpcGroup/index.php

</IfModule>
```

But it's not working.

One .htaccess which on my root have this coding:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: This is for your [Reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), what I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on recent comment, update the root `.htaccess` to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/EpcGroup [NC]    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and the one inside your `EpcGroup` directory to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /EpcGroup/

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^[^\.]+$ $0.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule ^[^\.]+$ $0.html [NC,L]

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```